# Python3 // JSON Returns on API with unencoded characters

Tags: json, python-3.x, encoding, utf-8

I have an API that returns information taken via WebScraping (requests, BeautifulSoup, etc), and this information must be returned without characters like \ u *****. I need the return with "ã, é, ê, ç" and etc, because another API (which is not in python) will consume data from this JSON, and also people will read the return of that JSON in a browser.

So, my problem is: How can I return a JSON with UTF-8 (or Latin) encoding in python, since the text I need to output is in Portuguese (BR)?

I've already try to use .enconding("utf-8") in the string before insert that in the JSON, but that didn't work.

For example, when I get the return above, the text returns me an Unencoded text.

Someone can help me, please?

```
status = "True"; 
if status == "True":
   texto = "Processos"
   dataFull = []
   stringMsg = "Processo(s) não encontrado(s)"
   dataFull.append ({"processos":"","qtdProcessos":"0", "mensagem":stringMsg})
   LISTAGEM = {text:dataFull}
   return [LISTAGEM[key] for key in sorted(LISTAGEM.keys())]
```

The return that I expect is:

```
[
  [
    {
      "mensagem": "Processo(s) não encontrado(s)",
      "processos": "",
      "qtdProcessos": "0"
    }
  ]
]
```

But I'm getting, at Chrome browser, when I run the API (localhost:XX/api/v1/processos):

```
[
  [
    {
      "mensagem": "Processo(s) n\u00e3o encontrado(s)",
      "processos": "",
      "qtdProcessos": "0"
    }
  ]
]
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Other APIs should be fine with this, since the JSON specs say that any character can be escaped with `\uNNNN` sequences. If you want the JSON to be more human-readable, you have to check if the framework (the requests library, I guess) allows you to control the JSON serialisation parameters.

Comment: If the framework doesn't give you this option, you can serialise yourself with `payload = json.dumps(LISTAGEM, ensure_ascii=False)`. Maybe you have to add an `.encode('utf8')`. You'll have to manually set the content-type header to "application/json" in this case. Note that you shouldn't use Latin-1 encoding, JSON must always be encoded with one of the UTF encodings.

Comment: @lenz Thank you for the answer. I've already tried both your suggestions, and both ways, don't seems to work it out... At the return(payload), where payload = json.dumps(LISTAGEM, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf-8') , I've got an error: "Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable"...

Comment: @lenz so, I tried also: 

  LISTAGEM2 = '[{"processos":"Não há","qtdProcessos":0, "mensagem":"Processo(s) não encontrado(s)"}]'
  parsed = json.loads(LISTAGEM2)
  payload2 = json.dumps(parsed, indent=4, sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False)
  return(payload2)


But the return was: "[\n    {\n        \"mensagem\": \"Processo(s) n\u00e3o encontrado(s)\",\n        \"processos\": \"N\u00e3o h\u00e1\",\n        \"qtdProcessos\": 0\n    }\n]"

Comment: Your framework seems to really want to produce plain-ASCII JSON. If you can't find a way to control the serialisation, you have to switch to another library.

Comment: Another solution might be some client-side script that parses the JSON and produces a human-friendly representation for display. Do you really need to have people looking at the raw JSON response?

Comment: @lenz Yes, the client wants to be able to read JSON. I've made the creation of extra APIs for the client, from which he can easily read. Thank you for your help!